# Deno Chart keeps drawing over the old one each time the function is called

Tags: typescript, deno

I´m having some troubles when generating an image file using deno_chart package. The first time i called this function, it goes smoothly but after this, each time that i called this function it overwrites the old one. I mean, you can show the updated charts but you can see the old one behind it.

Here is my code:

```
import Graph from 'https://deno.land/x/deno_chart/mod.ts';


export async function pintarGrafico(jsonUltimasLecturas: any): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {

  let imagenArray = null;
  //primero vamos a recorrer el json para obtener los valores máximos del consumo para pintar el gráfico y de los meses.
  let consumoMax = 0
  let numeroMeses = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonUltimasLecturas.length; i++) {
    if (jsonUltimasLecturas[i].CONSUMO> consumoMax ){
      consumoMax=jsonUltimasLecturas[i].CONSUMO
    } 
    numeroMeses++
  }
  


    let graph = new Graph( {
      
        titleText: 'Consumos anteriores',
        xAxisText: 'Mes',
        xPadding: 20,
        yAxisText: 'Consumo',
        titleColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        graphSegments_Y: 10,
        backgroundColor: {
          r: 0,
          g: 0,
          b: 0,
          a: 0,
        },
        yMax: consumoMax,
        bar_width: 40,
        graphSegments_X: numeroMeses+1,
      
        xTextColor:     'rgb(0,0,0)',
        xSegmentColor:  'rgb(0,0,0)',
        yTextColor:     'rgb(0,0,0)',
        ySegmentColor:  'rgb(0,0,0)',
      
        // Verbose Logging (Optional)
        verbose: true,
      });
      
      // Random Bar Generation with Colors!
      const COLORS = [
        '#345C7D', '#F7B094', '#F5717F', '#F7B094',
        '#6C5B7A',
      ]
      
   

      graph.draw()
      graph.save('image.png');


  return graph.toBuffer(); // returns ArrayBuffer of the chart image  
}
```

What am i missing?

I checked if components are instanciated, and it seems to be fine. maybe is a problem with the canvas library?